# Turning mvc4 application into spa using sammy.js

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, sammy.js

I want to convert the below MVC URL in to #tag URL for sammy.js routing purpose.

Please let me know how can i do this.

Comment: please clarify your question which URL?

Comment: Yes, please clarify your question to be more specific. As far as I am aware, there is no generic "ASP.NET MVC 4" adapter for Sammy.js, so you'd have to roll this code yourself.

Comment: I am replacing the link  <a href="@Url.Action(" index", "Home" , null)"></a> with  <a href="~/#/home/index/"> and its working fine.   Now i have one more link which is having the third parameter like     *<a href="@Url.Action("Analysis", "Team", new { id= string.Empty })"> how can i send the 3rd parameter in the hash tag URL like <a href="~/#/team/analysis/">